# Switching between UIViewControllers in story board

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

As someone who usually used separate xibs in the past I thought I'd give storyboard a go as it seemed a lot simpler to use and much easier to develop with. I've been writing an application where the essential set up is this:

At the top of all this is a UINavigationController (first level). Then I have Multiple UIViewControllers (second level) with buttons in them which you can tap to switch between the second level UIViewControllers.

However a problem occurs when I start switching between the second level UIViewControllers. I first thought this was an initialisation problem with the NSMutableArrays because in my code I have a NSTimer set to loop periodically and found when I set a breakpoint during it, when I went forward to the next timer tick event there appeared to be different instances of the same NSMutableArrays and it seemed a gamble to try and insert new values into these array with it sometimes working, sometimes not (as it may or may not insert into the correct instance).

Then, looking at the memory usage under Debug Navigator I found the issue. **Each time I "switched" between the UIViewControllers a new UIViewController was being initiated, along with all new variables.**

The code I am using to switch between them is

```
-(void) perform {
[[[self sourceViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];    
}
```

Or essentially a push segue transition. This also explains why when I tried to switch back to my view, the data on that view was lost as it is a complete new view.

Does anyone know how to switch between multiple ones of these UIViewControllers (say 5) essentially like a UITabViewController would except without the tab bar being present?

Comment: When you push a VC in NavigationController, the VC will initialize, so all its corresponding views will also initialize. Also your question is not clear, make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option you can do this: You can use a tabbarcontroller for switching viewcontroller and hidden the tabbar. Then on buttonclick setthe tabbar index.

Second option you can do this: Create one more view controller and in this viewcontroller subview the all switching viewController and when you want to switch viewcontroller just bring that viewcontroller view to front by delegate.

Comment: Could you briefly explain how I could implement the first option? Would it be easy to implement in Story board?

Comment: yes it is easy just add the viewcontroller in a tabbar controller then add this line     [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];

Comment: Ended up using this. Only problem I had was that any UIElements that couldn't be seen under where the tab bar would be had problems unless I specified Simulated metrics bottom bar to None and modified the tab bar controller to have an alpha of 0.5 and set it to not be user inter-actable and checked hidden.

Comment: use this [self.tabbarcontroller.tabbar setHidden:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the navigation bar and other features provided by your top level navigation controller?

If not,  you could use a `UIPageViewController` instead.
You set up all your second level view controllers and then just have to tell the page view controller which one to display.

If you implement the associated delegate methods, it will automatically provide swipe gestures to switch between them and nice animations to get them on and off screen.
You can also get it to put a `UIPageControl` at the bottom showing a dot for each VC with the dot for the current VC highlighted.